# Only Printing 1 line to textbox, instead off all statements c#

Tags: c#

I'm trying to print all true statements from my file to textbox. For some reason only 1 line is appearing. I can't see an error or missed bracket.

I have radio buttons that I have assigned a variable to then print to the document, which is working. I used .toString(); because I was getting an error of can't change string to int, when i was trying to show the summary of this in the txtbox.

`

```
//if radio button is checked write to file
            if (rdoIndoor.Checked == true)
            {
                rdoIndoor.Text = iIndoor.ToString();
                sw.WriteLine(rdoIndoor.Text);
            }
            else
            {
                rdoOutdoor.Text = iOutdoor.ToString();
                sw.WriteLine(rdoOutdoor.Text);
            }

            //if radio button is checked write to file
            if (rdoFree.Checked == true)
            {
                rdoFree.Text = iFree.ToString();

                sw.WriteLine(rdoFree.Text);
            }
            else
            {
                rdoPriced.Text = iPriced.ToString();

                sw.WriteLine(rdoPriced.Text);
            }
```

Code:

```
                        txtSummary.Text = "Music events were most popular        this year" + Environment.NewLine;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        txtSummary.Text = "Theatre events were most popular this year" + Environment.NewLine;
                    }

                    //find out if free or pri string line = string.Empty;
        while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            for (int iCount = 0; iCount < sMonths.Length; iCount++)
            {


                //conditions
                if (iCount == 2)
                {
                    sMonths[iCount] = sr.ReadLine();

                    //find out which type of event was more popular within the year 

                    if (iCountDance > iCountArt && iCountDance > iCountMusic && iCountDance > iCountTheatre)
                    {
                        txtSummary.Text = "Dance events were most popular this year" + Environment.NewLine;
                    }
                    else if (iCountArt > iCountDance && iCountArt > iCountMusic && iCountArt > iCountTheatre)
                    {
                        txtSummary.Text = "Art events were most popular this year" + Environment.NewLine;
                    }
                    else if (iCountMusic > iCountDance && iCountMusic > iCountArt && iCountMusic > iCountTheatre)
                    {ced events were more popular this year
                    if (iPriced > iFree)
                    {
                        txtSummary.Text = "Priced events were more popular this year" + Environment.NewLine;
                    }
                    else if (iFree > iPriced)
                    {
                        txtSummary.Text = "Free events were moree popular this year" + Environment.NewLine;
                    }

                    iAttendanceTotal = iAttendance * iAttendance;
                    txtSummary.Text = "At least " + iAttendanceTotal + " people attended events over the year" + Environment.NewLine;
                }
```

Comment: @LP. Gonçalves  Yes, it was working from file to listbox before, but because of the for loop it would just repetitively loop, so I changed to read to textbox, and it no longer works.

Answer (score 0):

Replace this

```
txtSummary.Text =...
```

With this:

```
txtSummary.Text +=
```

Because Everytime you assign new value it replaces the stored value with new one.

Hope it helps!